# Submitting Portion of Form to a Separate Action

Tags: ajax, forms

In my shopping cart for my online store I'd like there to be a checkbox to allow people to opt-in for my newsletter. But the email address for the newsletter needs to be submitted to a separate form action than the shopping cart action.

Is it possible for me to submit part of a form to another action but still submit to the shopping cart form action and render wherever the shopping cart action would take me?

Comment: ...and you're using MVC, it seems?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post your data using jquery:

This first ajax call will submit to your cart action:

```
function SubmitCart()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cart action url',
        data: { data1: $('#data1').val(), data2: $('#data2').val(), data3: $('#data3').val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
             // Action completed.
        }
    });
}
```

this other bit here will submit to your newsletter action:

```
function SubmitNewsletter()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'newsletter action url',
        data: { email: $('#email_fields').val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
             // Action completed.
        }
    });
}
```

Now, you would have a submit button somewhere:

```
<input type="button" id="sumit_all" name="sumit_all" value="send" />
<input type="checkbox" id="subscribeNewsletter" name="subscribeNewsletter" />
```

and the jQuery script:

```
$("sumit_all").click(function() {
   SubmitCart();
   if ($('#subscribeNewsletter').is(':checked'))
   {
      SubmitNewsletter();
   }
});
```

Comment: This looks nice and simple enough. So will the shopping cart form still perform it's submission as well?

Comment: this is an ajax submission. you decide which field are going to be added to the submission process. you do not have a real post-back.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. But I want the shopping cart to still process the rest of the form as well and take them to the next step in the checkout process. How would I properly implement this in the form? Thanks!

Comment: @Marc: It seems more like a philosophical problem. Why can't you just use one form and decide in the action what to do? Maybe creating a new action which calls the 2 methods? I'll extend my answer with the alternative.

Comment: I'm going to go with what you have above. I think that'll work just great. The shopping cart form is generated by WP E-Commerce so I don't want to mess with what it does a whole lot. I think this will do the job without me having to change a whole lot. Thanks!